# C#. Как отслеживать длительность просмотра видео в реальном времени?

Tags: c#, .net

Как отследить длительность просмотра видео на ютуб в реальном времени?
Сценарий:
1. Проигрывается видео (ютуб) в обычном браузере (или браузере созданном на базе C#).
2. Считывается секундомер длительности просмотра видео.
3. Секундомер выводится на окно Виндовс формы.

Т.е. время просмотра синхронно с плеером отображается в форме
[image: Прилагаю скриншот]